# Problem with fitting the search bar and setting up options for the dropdown list

Tags: html, css

I am making a music storage device, similar to MAL if you are familiar, for school.

I need to fit the search bar and integrate different options (the customization options) in the dropdown.

```html
<ul>    
    <li><a class="active" href="#all" type= "button">All</a></li>
    <li><a href="#favourites" type= "button">Favourites</a></li>
    <li><a href="#wishlist" type= "button">Wishlist</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" type="button"><div class="dropdown"></div>Customize</a></li>
    <li style="float:right"><a class="active" type= "submit">Search</a></li>
    <input style="float:right" placeholder="Album, Band, ect..." name="searchKey"></input>
</ul>

<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="background_Colour.php">Background</a>
        <a href="#">Font</a>
        <a href="#">Text Colour</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please add a code snippet!

Comment: i have no idea what that is

Answer (score 1):

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);
 
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


.nav {
    background: #000;
    height: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
}
 
.nav li {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
}

.nav li a {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    line-height: 60px;
    padding: 0 26px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-left: 1px solid #2e2e2e;
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.nav li a:hover {
    background-color: #2e2e2e;
}
 
#settings a {
    padding: 18px;
    height: 24px;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 24px;
}

#search {
    width: 357px;
    margin: 4px;
}
#search_text{
    width: 297px;
    padding: 15px 0 15px 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    border: 0 none;
    height: 52px;
    margin-right: 0;
    color: white;
    outline: none;
    background: #1f7f5c;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: all 0.15s;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
    color: white;
}
:-moz-placeholder {
    color: white;
}
::-moz-placeholder { 
    color: white;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { 
    color: white;
}
#search_button {
    border: 0 none;
    background: #1f7f5c url("") center no-repeat;
    width: 60px;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    height: 52px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#options a{
    border-left: 0 none;
}
#options&gt;a {
    background-image: url(triangle.png);
    background-position: 85% center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-right: 42px;
}
.subnav {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 110%;
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.1s;
    background: #232323;
}
.subnav li {
    float: none;
}
.subnav li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2e2e2e;
}
#options:hover .subnav {
    visibility: visible;
    top: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<br><br>
<ul class="nav">
    <li id="settings">
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">#</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">#</a>
    </li>
    <li id="search">
        <form action="" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" placeholder="Search"/>
            <input type="button" name="search_button" id="search_button"></a>
        </form>
    </li>
    <li id="options">
        <a href="#">Dropdown</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">#</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
  </form>
```

Comment: thank you for the help, but i am not sure how the drop down works, since  it seems to be not working

Comment: Dropdown working, if you running code snippet background color is white, dropdown under #, use my css code  to see dropdown

Comment: Just to be sure, the code from ArturHarutyunyan works fine for me too.